# R combine every colnames with every colnames

Tags: r

I want to combine the every item in my array, `colnames` with every other item in `colnames`. For example, if `colnames` is this:

```
colnames <- c("sam","frank","pete")
```

Then, I want this as my output:

```
"sam_sam",
"sam_frank",
"sam_pete",
"frank_sam",
"frank_frank",
"frank_pete",
"pete_sam",
"pete_frank",
"pete_pete"
```

Without using a loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `c( outer(cnames, cnames, FUN = paste, sep="_"))`

Comment: Thank Toastrackenigma

Answer (score 0):

Or try `expand.grid(cnames, cnames)` to have all combinations in two separate columns

Comment: Thanks Taeke for your help